# Generating Bitmaps with custom text for map markers - OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, google-maps, bitmap, markers

I have a mapview that displays your route traveled in a car, and has a seekbar that allows you to move along the path, displaying a map marker at each location with the speed on it. These map markers (Bitmaps) are generated at run-time since the speeds need to be placed on them. The problem I am having is that a trip may have hundreds of locations that require a new map marker/ Bitmap to be generated. I am currently creating a new bitmap for each location in an AsyncTask. For a long trip, the app force closes due to an OutOfMemoryError. I need a way to swap out the text on the map markers so that I can create 1 Bitmap.
Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: showing some code will be easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

Bipmaps are always a expensive operation when it comes to mobile development. What I would suggest you is to have a lazy loading of marker (Bitmaps). So, what you can do is first know the visible area and the bounds corresponding to that and fetch markers only when the map is scrolled in that region. This wont consume a lot of your memory at run-time and would fetch bitmaps only when needed.

Here is a sample code:

```
 GoogleMap = theMap;
LatLngBounds bounds = this.theMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;

LatLng placeLL = new LatLng(yourLatitude, yourLangtitude);

    if (bounds.contains(placeLL)) {
    //Do what you wanted to do with the markers inside the visible area
}
```

Hope this Helps!!